# How to define General deterministic function in PyMC

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, mcmc, pymc3

In my model, I need to obtain the value of my deterministic variable from a set of parent variables using a complicated python function.

Is it possible to do that?

Following is a pyMC3 code which shows what I am trying to do in a simplified case.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm


#Predefine values on two parameter Grid (x,w) for a set of i values (1,2,3)
idata = np.array([1,2,3])
size= 20
gridlength = size*size
Grid = np.empty((gridlength,2+len(idata)))
for x in range(size):
    for w in range(size):
        # A silly version of my real model evaluated on grid.
        Grid[x*size+w,:]= np.array([x,w]+[(x**i + w**i) for i in idata])

# A function to find the nearest value in Grid and return its product with third variable z
def FindFromGrid(x,w,z):
    return Grid[int(x)*size+int(w),2:] * z

#Generate fake Y data with error
yerror = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=9.0, size=len(idata))
ydata = Grid[16*size+12,2:]*3.6 + yerror  # ie. True x= 16, w= 12 and z= 3.6


with pm.Model() as model:

    #Priors
    x = pm.Uniform('x',lower=0,upper= size)
    w = pm.Uniform('w',lower=0,upper =size)
    z = pm.Uniform('z',lower=-5,upper =10)

    #Expected value
    y_hat = pm.Deterministic('y_hat',FindFromGrid(x,w,z))

    #Data likelihood
    ysigmas = np.ones(len(idata))*9.0 
    y_like = pm.Normal('y_like',mu= y_hat, sd=ysigmas, observed=ydata)

    # Inference...
    start = pm.find_MAP() # Find starting value by optimization
    step = pm.NUTS(state=start) # Instantiate MCMC sampling algorithm
    trace = pm.sample(1000, step, start=start, progressbar=False) # draw 1000 posterior samples using NUTS sampling


print('The trace plot')
fig = pm.traceplot(trace, lines={'x': 16, 'w': 12, 'z':3.6})
fig.show()
```

When I run this code, I get error at the y_hat stage, because the `int()` function inside the `FindFromGrid(x,w,z)` function needs integer not FreeRV.

Finding `y_hat` from a pre calculated grid is important because my real model for y_hat does not have an analytical form to express.

I have earlier tried to use OpenBUGS, but I found out [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119883/how-to-define-function-in-openbugs) it is not possible to do this in OpenBUGS. Is it possible in PyMC ?

## Update

Based on an example in pyMC github page, I found I need to add the following decorator to my `FindFromGrid(x,w,z)` function.

```
@pm.theano.compile.ops.as_op(itypes=[t.dscalar, t.dscalar, t.dscalar],otypes=[t.dvector])
```

This seems to solve the above mentioned issue. But I cannot use NUTS sampler anymore since it needs gradient.

Metropolis seems to be not converging.

Which step method should I use in a scenario like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the correct solution with `as_op`.

Regarding the convergence: Are you using `pm.Metropolis()` instead of `pm.NUTS()` by any chance? One reason this could not converge is that `Metropolis()` by default samples in the joint space while often Gibbs within Metropolis is more effective (and this was the default in pymc2). Having said that, I just merged this: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/pull/587 which changes the default behavior of the `Metropolis` and `Slice` sampler to be non-blocked by default (so within Gibbs). Other samplers like `NUTS` that are primarily designed to sample the joint space still default to blocked. You can always explicitly set this with the kwarg `blocked=True`.

Anyway, update pymc with the most recent master and see if convergence improves. If not, try the `Slice` sampler.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess, what is happening in my example model above is that the variables are highly correlated. So It is getting stuck at some point after a few chains of MC. Is there a way to increase the step size in the jumps MC take? I was also wondering why I am getting an error no grad() attribute for my function, while using pm.find_MAP() if it is using Nelder-Mead optimization, which does not require derivatives.

Comment: Yes, `find_MAP()` with Nelder-Mead should work. Can you open an issue on github about this with some code to reproduce?

Comment: Regarding getting stuck, those are the pains of MCMC. If correlation is the problem you could try tweaking the proposal distribution for Metropolis-Hastings or just run more samples.

Comment: Thanks. I shall post an issue in github.